# How can we access objects declared in a javascript file in another file in a sencha touch application?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

How can we access objects declared in a javascript file in another JS file in the same sencha touch application??
Help from anyone good in Sencha Touch is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Sensa Touch but in general in JavaScript you can either share them by using a global object, or pass object references between functions (whether in the same JS file or not).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the Javascript is in a different file isn't really a huge matter. It's more a matter of understanding scope & global variables etc.

If you create a variable in the global scope of one file:

```
var hello = 'hello';
```

Then this is of course available in another file:

```
alert(hello + ' world');
```

(Although you'd want to get the order correct when you import those files into the HTML document)

All that said, global variables are normally advised against, and Sencha Touch provides a way to namespace variables too: see Ext.namespace in http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext